# Uniform Continuity: Is this a good proof?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Show that $f(x)=1/x^2$ is not uniformly continuous one the set $(0,1]$

Using the *Sequential Criterion for Nonuniform Continuity* - which states that

> a function $f:A \rightarrow  $ **R** fails to be uniformly continuous on A iff there exists a particular $\epsilon_0$>0 and two sequences ($x_n$) and ($y_n$) in A, satisfying $|x_n -y_n| \rightarrow 0$, but $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)|\ge \epsilon_0$

I would say:

> Take ($x_n$) = $\frac{1}{n}$ and ($y_n$)=$\frac{1}{n^2}$. Obviously $|\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}| \rightarrow 0$, but $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| = |n^2 - n^4| \ge 12 $, for example for n $\ge$ 2

Comment: Uniformly continuous functions take Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences. That seems as the easiest way to show that your function isn't uniformly continuous.

Comment: Or: If $f$ is uniformly continuous on a bounded domain, then $f$ is bounded. Your $f$ is not bounded, but $(0,1]$ is.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 5 questions in the last 24 hours. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, Stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This CW answer is intended to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

There is nothing wrong with your argument involving the Sequential Criterion.

As pointed out in the comments, you could also have approached this by:

- exhibiting a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $(f(x_n))_n$ is not Cauchy;
- showing that the range of $f$ is not bounded, while its domain is.